# Is MySQL 8 no longer sorting when GROUP BY?

Tags: mysql, group-by

Usually my queries are using `GROUP BY` either by `DATE` or `DATETIME` column. So far in MySQL 5.7 the result set was always chronologically sorted. But recently after upgrading to MySQL 8 by accident I found a bizzare result set where DATETIME was just partly sorted.

`where time>='2023-08-01' and time<'2023-08-10'`

The result set started with all the hours of `2023-08-02` and the hours of `2023-08-01` were placed after `2023-08-09`. This situation happens rarely, but I cannot rely that it will not happen as this unsorted result set distorts the charts, which are build upon it.

According to [following blog](https://dev.mysql.com/blog-archive/removal-of-implicit-and-explicit-sorting-for-group-by/):

> In MySQL, historically GROUP BY was used to provide sorting as well. If a query specified GROUP BY, the result was sorted as if ORDER BY was present in the query. [...] This has changed in 8.0 as it no longer supports either implicit or explicit sorting for GROUP BY.

And according to [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/order-by-optimization.html)

> Previously (MySQL 5.7 and lower), GROUP BY sorted implicitly under certain conditions. In MySQL 8.0, that no longer occurs, so specifying ORDER BY NULL at the end to suppress implicit sorting (as was done previously) is no longer necessary. However, query results may differ from previous MySQL versions. To produce a given sort order, provide an ORDER BY clause.

My question is should I from now on in the case of using MySQL 8 always put `ORDER BY` after `GROUP BY`, so that to have chronologically sorted results in 100% of the cases? Should the query end to look like following?

```
GROUP BY TimeColumn
ORDER BY TimeColumn;
```

In the case of only `GROUP BY` the `EXPLAIN` command is **not** showing `Using filesort`, while when there is also `ORDER BY` clause the query optimizer **is** `Using filesort`. For comparison in MySQL 5.7 when ordering is done when grouping there is **no** `Using filesort`.

`Using filesort` is possibly making the excution of queries harder, respectively slower, so is MySQL 8 less effective than MySQL 5.7 when the idea is to get the same chronologically ordered and grouped by `DATE` or `DATETIME` column result set?

Should I increase the value of `sort_buffer_size` from the default 0.25MB?

I am not posting table structures or other more detailed information, because my question is more general.

I am using MyISAM engine and started considering moving to MariaDB, because MyISAM is quite abandoned in the newer MySQL versions. According to [MariaDB documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/group-by/):

> By default, if a GROUP BY clause is present, the rows in the output will be sorted by the expressions used in the GROUP BY.

This means that the problem I am facing with MySQL 8 and thus posting my question here is not relevant to MariaDB.

Comment: I'm not aware of the specifics of MySQL, but I don't know of any RDBMS that sorts when given (only) a group-by. It could be a side-effect of using an index or something, but unless you explicitly specify an order-by, any order you may get is a coincidence.

Comment: It is good practice to not over-rely on a specific implementation and always specify the order if one is needed. As to your `sort_buffer_size`, I can't comment on that, because we have no idea about your data, queries and server hardware.

Comment: "So far in MySQL 5.7 the result set was always chronologically sorted..." -- That may have been a bug in that version of MySQL. According to the SQL Standard, in the absence of an `ORDER BY` clause, the engine is free to return the rows in any ordering... and that ordering can change over time without notice.

Comment: "...My question is should I from now on in the case of using MySQL 8 always put ORDER BY..." -- Yes. If you need the rows in a specific ordering, always use ORDER BY. Otherwise you may get lucky and get the rows in one ordering, but later on, if you upgrade the database "the query will start to fail". Add ORDER BY and sleep well at night.

Comment: @TheImpaler What about when I query direct values for the objects in the database like ```select object, date, counter1, counter2...``` without any aggregation, so no need of ```group by```? Can I expect chronologically ordered by date results without ```order by``` clause?

Comment: @Ivaylo No, again, no. In the absence of an ORDER BY clause, the engine is free to return the rows in any ordering, and that ordering can change at any time without notice.

Comment: @TheImpaler Could you please answer officially to my question, so that to accept your answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is should I from now on in the case of using MySQL 8 always put ORDER BY

Yes. If you need the rows in a specific ordering, always use ORDER BY.

Otherwise you may get lucky and get the rows in one ordering, but later on if you upgrade the database or change the data in any way, "the query will suddenly start to fail". Add ORDER BY and sleep well at night.

Again, in the absence of an ORDER BY clause, the engine is free to return the rows in any ordering, and that ordering can change at any time without notice.

Comment: yes, always specify order by if you want a specific ordering.  the exception was mysql before version 8, where order by was documented as defaulting to group by.  but no one should be using these no longer supported versions.